Minimum of a continuous function on the interior of the unit ball
I consider the set $S = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x\rVert < 1\}$ and $f : S\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function satisfying
$$
f(x)\geq\frac{1}{1-\lVert x\rVert}\quad (1)
$$
The problem I want to solve is
$$
\inf_{x\in S}f(x)\quad (Q)
$$
We can prove that $Q$ has a finite value using $(1)$ since it is bounded below. Now I would like to use a method of "exhaustion" that consists to consider the following sequence of problem for $k\geq 1$ :
$$
\inf_{x\in S_k}f(x)\:\text{with}\: S_k =\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x\rVert \leq 1 - \frac{1}{k}\}\quad (Q_k)
$$
and observe that by continuity of $f$ and compactness of the $S_k$ we have a solution to the problem $Q_k$. The next step is to consider a sequence $x_k$ defined as follows :

$x_1$ is a solution of $Q_1$

for $k\geq 2$, $x_k = x_{k-1}$ if $x_{k-1}$ is a solution of $Q_k$, otherwise $x_k$ is any solution of $Q_k$


It can be shown that it implies that the sequence $\lVert x_k\rVert$ is increasing. Now by compactness of the unit ball, we can extract a convergent subsequence, lets say $\bar{x}_k$ with limit $\bar{x}\in B(0,1)$. We observe two things :

the subsequence still have the property that the sequence of norms is increasing

the sequence $f(\bar{x}_{k})_{k}$ is decreasing.


This implies that $\lVert\bar{x}\rVert < 1$ : otherwise, using $(1)$ we get that the sequence $(f(\bar{x}_k))_k$ goes to $\infty$, so letting $M>f(\bar{x}_1)$ we have that for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ :
$$
f(\bar{x}_k)\geq M>f(\bar{x}_1), \forall k\geq N
$$
which contradicts the second observation. Hence $\bar{x}\in S$ and by continuity $(f(\bar{x}_k)_k$ converges, decreasingly, to $f(\bar{x})$. Now let $y\in S$, we have that $\lVert y\rVert < 1$, this implies the existence of some $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $y\in S_{k_0}$, hence we get
$$
f(y)\geq f(\bar{x}_{k_0})\geq f(\bar{x})
$$
This proves that problem $Q$ has a solution.
I would like to know if it is correct please. I think the main ideas are here but I would like to have some advice to know if it is clear enough please.
Thank you a lot !

I think you mean $f\colon S\to \mathbb R$

@FedericoFallucca Of course, thank you !

What precisely do you mean by solving (Q)? The infimum exists and is $\ge 1$. Do you want to find $\xi$ where the infimum is attained?

Yes sorry I wanted to fined where the infimum is attained !

It seems that you want to prove that $f$ attains a minimum at some $\bar x \in S$.
Certainly the infimum $m = \inf_{x \in S}f(x)$ exists and is $\ge 1$ since the RHS of $(1)$ is $\ge 1$ for all $x \in S$, but it is not a priori clear that it is attained at some $\bar x \in S$.
Your proof via constructing the sequence $(x_k)$ by taking $x_k  \in S_k$ such that $f(x) \ge f(x_k)$ for all $x \in S_k$ is correct. However, you do
not need to define "$x_k = x_{k-1}$ if $x_{k-1}$ is a solution of $Q_k$", just take any solution. Then you cannot be sure that $(\lVert x_k \rVert)$ is increasing, but that is irrelevant. It suffices to know that $(f(x_k))$ is decreasing.
You can do it simpler without sequences as follows.
Let $r \in \mathbb R$ satisfy $f(0) = \dfrac{1}{1-r}$, i.e. $r = 1 - \dfrac{1}{f(0)}$. Since $f(0) \ge 1$, we have $0 < \dfrac{1}{f(0)} \le 1$, thus $0 \le r < 1$.
$f$ attains a minimum $m$ on the closed ball $B_r = \{ x \mid  \lVert x \rVert \le r \} \subset S$. Let $f(\bar x) = m$ with $\bar x \in B_r$.
We claim that $m$ is the minimum of $f$. It is attained at $\bar x \in B_r \subset S$.
In fact, for $x \in S \setminus B_r$ we have $\lVert x \rVert > r$ and therefore
$$f(x) \ge \frac{1}{1-\lVert x \rVert} > \frac{1}{1-r} = f(0) \ge f(\bar x).$$

Beautiful, I was trying to do something similar :)

Clearly better than what I expect, thank you a lot !

In fact you have proven something stronger than just prove the existence of a solution to the problem $Q$ : there exists a solution of one the "intermediary problem" $Q_k$ which is a solution of $Q$ !

Your argument seems nice and correct. I suggest also this other approach that maybe can be useful for you. However, at the end is more or less the same of your argument.
Let us consider the set $C:=\{x \in S \colon 0\leq f(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}\}=f^{-1}([0,\frac{1}{2}])$. Since $f$ is continuos, then $C$ is closed in $S$ and also bounded.
Let us assume that it there exists $0< \epsilon<1$ such that $C\subseteq B(0,\epsilon)\subset S$. Then $C$ is compact and by continuity of $f$ it there exists a minimum $x_0\in C$ for $f\colon C\to \mathbb R$. However, this is also a minimum for $f\colon S\to \mathbb R$ because given $x\in  S$, then
either $x\in C$, and so $f(x)\geq f(x_0)$;
or
$x\notin C$, and so either $f(x)<0$ (that is impossible), or $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}\geq f(x_0)$.
Instead, what happen if it does not exists $\epsilon$ for which $C\subseteq B(0,\epsilon)\subset S$? This means that it there exists a sequence $x_k\in C$ converging to $x$ such that $\vert \vert x\vert \vert =1$.
However, this means $f(x_k)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and it contradicts the fact that $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{1-\vert \vert x\vert\vert}$.
Where is the problem of this argument? What I said works whenever we are sure that $C$ is nonempty. However, we can observe that
$$S=f^{-1}([0, \infty))=\cup_{k\in \mathbb N} f^{-1}([0, k])$$
so that it there exists $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^{-1}([0, k])\neq \emptyset $.
Now you can apply the previous game to $f^{-1}([0,k])$ to guarantee the existence of a minimum on $S$.
Note that here we are only using that $f$ has to be greater than a function going to infinity on the boundary of $B(0,1)$.

$S= (0,1) \subset T = [0,1], f(x) = x$. What is $x_0$?

Ah yeah, you're right. I had a mistake, because $C$ is closed in $S$, but it could not be closed on $\mathbb R^n$. I try to correct it.

Thank you for this perspective @FedericoFallucca !

You're welcome :)
